# How can I update the a field based on a calculation of another field of a second DB?

Tags: sql, calculation

I would appreciate your help with the creation of a SQL query.
I have a table called `Purchases`.
There is a column in the table called PurchaseGender, it currently has NO information.

I have another table called `Additional Info` with 2 columns: MalePurchases and FemalePurchases. Each of these 2 columns are populated with numbers.

These columns will be:

| Client Id | FemalePurchases | MalePurchases |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1234 | 10 | 2 |
| 5678 | 3 | 5 |

I would like to populate the PurchaseGender column of `Purchases` based on a calculation.

Continuing with the above example, I want to indicate that the PurchaseGender of a person is Female is they have bought MORE female items.
On the other hand, the PurchaseGender will be Male if they have bought MORE male items

For Client 1234, their PurchaseGender will be Female while for the Client 5678 their PurchaseGender will be Male.

Both tables have the `Client ID` column in common.

What would the SQL query look like?

Comment: Updating joined table syntax varies by RDBMS, so please TAG your RDBMS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that 'DB' means table here...

EDIT: Moved the `CASE` expression to a CTE and added a `WHERE` clause to the `UPDATE`, to run repeatedly.

```
;WITH PGender
AS
(
  SELECT a.ClientId,
     CASE WHEN a.FemalePurchases > a.MalePurchases THEN 'Female'
          WHEN a.FemalePurchases < a.MalePurchases THEN 'Male'
          ELSE 'Balanced' END AS 'PurchaseGender'
  FROM AdditionalInfo a
)

UPDATE p
SET p.PurchaseGender = pg.PurchaseGender
FROM Purchases p
  INNER JOIN PGender pg ON p.ClientId = pg.ClientId
WHERE p.PurchaseGender != pg.PurchaseGender
```

Comment: This makes perfect sense. It is simpler than I thought. Thanks so much!